# how to automatically start audio recording once user is inside the audio page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a audio recording page which starts when I tap in the button and stop when i tap the button once again

```
ElevatedButton(
      child: Icon(
        recorder.isRecording ? Icons.stop : Icons.mic,
        size: 80,
      ),
      onPressed: () async {
        if (recorder.isRecording) {
          await stop();
          context.pop();
        } else {
          await record();
        }
        setState(() {});
      },
```

how can I automatically start recording once I open the audio recording page and tap it to stop and tap again to start?

I tried to put the record function in initstate but it didn't work

```
void initState() {
     super.initState(); 
     initRecorder(); 
     record(); 
        }
```

Comment: Which package you use for recording >

Comment: add your start record function

Comment: flutter sound package

Comment: Future initRecorder() async {
    final status = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      throw 'Microphone permission not granted';
    }
    await recorder.openRecorder();
    isRecorderReady = true;
    recorder.setSubscriptionDuration(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  Future record() async {
    if (!isRecorderReady) {
      return;
    }
    await recorder.startRecorder(toFile: 'audio');
  }